# How do I overlay an element over a portion of a large image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, react-native, flexbox

The high level idea is that I'm trying to draw a demo of my app within my app. Observe the following images:

[image: Rectangles]

[image: Sketch]

Here are the details.

The large black rectangle is the boundary of the phone screen. The green area is margin space. The pink area represents an image of the outline of a phone, and the blue area is a video of my app, sitting over the image. Together they showcase my app in action on a phone. They are centered horizontally. The bottom of the blue video touches the top of the yellow text box. So the tricky part is that the pink phone image is actually a very large image of a full phone, but I need it to be scaled down, and "cut off" by the yellow section. The margin between the top of the pink and the top of the screen is 80 pixels, although if it makes it easier we can say the phone image is like 80% of the full screen size or something. I'm using the same phone image (iPhone 8) for a number of phone screen sizes (i.e. iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 11) so I shouldn't hardcode the numbers.

My existing code looks something like this, but the pink phone image has the top of the phone cut off (code in React-Native, although should be understandable regardless; I can provide a HTML translation if needed):

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 3, textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 80 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}></View>
            <Image style={{ marginTop: 'auto', height: 400, width: 375, position: 'absolute' }} source={require('assets/iphone.png')} resizeMode={'cover'} />
            <Video style={{ marginTop: 'auto', height: 350, width: 340, alignSelf: 'center' }} rate={2} source={require('assets/app.mp4')} shouldPlay={true} />
        </View>
    </View>
    <View style={{ flex: 2, paddingTop: "10%" }}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text>{item.text}</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

I figure I probably need to wrap the pink image in an image container div, but I'm not sure where to go from there. Could someone help me with this tricky CSS?

Comment: if you do not need to interact with the demo app from within the yellow part, the demo   app can be shown as an iframe.

Comment: @Karimov Can I use iframe in React Native? And does that change the CSS I need?

Comment: Example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/mature-milkshake

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using a background image and some padding. Using background-size and background-position, you can position the phone in the way you want. By adding a padding to the container, you can define how much of the background (the phone) should be visible.
Here is a crude example.

```css
.black{
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 350px;
  height: 600px;
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.phone{
  margin: 3rem 2rem 0 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 0;
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580910051074-3eb694886505?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1301&q=80");
    background-size: 250%;
    background-position: 48% 40%;
}
.content{
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  background: blue;
}
.yellow{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
 <div class="black">
   <div class="phone">
     <div class="content">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="yellow">

   </div>
 </div>
```